# C# - How to add a number to a already existing number?

Tags: c#

Basically my question is how i add to a number like a calculator does for example? My code currently looks like this but it does a add operation instead of adding the number behind the existing number.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            value1 = value1 + 1;
            output = value1;
            textresult.Text = output.ToString();
```

if the user presses the button twice it would be 2. I want it to be 11. How do i do this?

Comment: `output = value1.ToString() + 1.ToString();`

Comment: `output = value1 * 10 + 1`;

Comment: is the button they are pessing "1"  and it shouldn't be "22" but "11"?  If so, then the comments/answers will help,  otherwise....  explain yourself a bit more

Comment: @c.z. I think they still need to assign it to value1 as I'm guessing that's the member field they will need to keep updating

Comment: @KeithNicholas Yes I think you might be right. In which case, what's the line `output = value1` doing?

Comment: @c.z.  not a lot :)    I've seen new programmers do that before though, make variables as holding spots representing their thinking,  so they need a variable to do some magic stuff, then they need to output it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use string variable instead int variable

```
int a = 1;
int b = 1;
int c = a+b;
```

The result of c is 2

```
string a = "1";
string b = "1";
string c = a+b;
```

If you use string it will be "11"

Comment: You may want to show how this would be used with a `TextBox` and whatever the OP is using